# Generic Type to use for HTML controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, controls

Is there a type I can use in codebehind when looping through all controls on a web page to reference each type?

I need to read the `Value` of each, but types like `WebControl` and `HTMLGenericControl` don't have that property.

Thanks

Comment: I only see HtmlInputControl class. But It would work only for <input runat="server" ...> controls. If I understand your question, you seem to be looking for some jquery like .val() extension method on the control class. I guess you will have to write it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer is "No".

If anyone knows differently I'd like to hear :)